# PHP insert multiple array into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have add/remove input box using jQuery for add video link and add into database like this:

```
<input name="video[]" class="" value="" />
<input name="video[]" class="" value="" />
```

I check and filter empty value than insert not empty value into my database like this:

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();

foreach(array_filter($_POST['video']) as $video_url) {
if (!empty($video_url)) {


$value['video_data'] = serialize((array(
array_filter($_POST['video'])
)));


SQL::insert("INSERT INTO " . NEWS_FILES . " (url, id,type) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", $value['video_data'], $id, "video");
}
}
```

Now, in database I see two row for id:

[image]

BUT,  I need to insert one row for each id.

How do can I fix this ?

**edit:**

`$id = mysql_insert_id();`

Comment: Where is the code to create the `$id` variable..? That's what your question concerns and we have no informatoin on it.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: `$id = mysql_insert_id();`

Answer (score 0):

Have you marked the id field in the database table as Auto Increment or not?

Because as per the current code, the $id is not updated anywhere. So it assumes the default value and inserts.

I would suggest to initialize $id before starting the foreach loop and then doing an increment after the SQL statement is executed

```
SQL::insert("INSERT INTO " . NEWS_FILES . " (url, id,type) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", $value['video_data'], $id, "video");
$i++;
```

Comment: mysql_insert_id — It Gets the ID generated in the last query. I do not see any use of using mysql_insert_id the way you have done. Even if it gets initialized to some value, it does not get updated during the loop, so still the same id will be inserted. Also, you did not tell if the id column is auto increment or not?

Answer (score 0):

You must create array values by php 
$ar = new array();
$ar[]= null;
You submit form data multipart load
insert command by mysqldata
"Insert  data into table db " 
" for numbers all rows";

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have auto increment of id, you can use

```
$id = "select max(id) from  " .NEWS_FILES ; // execute sql and get maxid
```

than in your foreach add at a top  $id++;